# accessing all instances of the same select directive and the respective select values angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

So i have implemented a chosen dropdown in the following way.
A select box with "chosen" directive as an attribute which i use to update and initiliaze a list. there is also an ng-model on the select.

```
<select id="{{$index+1}}" class="chosen" data-placeholder="Enter 
    City..." chosen ng-model="cityName" ng-options="city.name for city in 
    cityList">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

this is what the directive looks like :

```
.directive('chosen', function($timeout){
return {
restrict:'A',
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
   // watcher to update chosen
}
}
```

How can i access all such select boxes in the DOM with the corresponding selected value ?

Comment: you can get the selected value in Controller using `$scope.cityName`

Comment: share more code about `chosen` directive.

Comment: you can put the selected value with `modelName` as key in `$rootScope` & can get all instances anywhere in your app.

Comment: could you help out with some code ?
I'm looking to keep this code at a directive level.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is use the iterator from the `ng-repeat` in the model name:

```
<div ng-repeat="gig in gigList">
    <select id="gigCity{{$index+1}}" class="chosen" chosen 
            placeholder="Enter City..." 
            ng-model="gig.cityName"
            ng-options="city.name for city in cityList">
        <option></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
for (let i=0; i<$scope.gigList.length; i++) {
    console.log(gigList[i].cityName);
};
```